# Trigger the method call when the session timeout in gwt

Tags: java, session, gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc

I would like to detect the session timeout and trigger the method call in server side of the GWT. Is it possible? 
My idea is that when the session is timeout in server side, I would like to do some data operation in database by server side program.
Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with GWT. GWT is concerned about the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using servlets, have a look at [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This should be fine for me. :)